# Trying to increment counter using character comparison

Tags: java, string, charat

I'm writing a method that is supposed to iterate through a string and increment a counter each time the letter `c` is found.  The method uses the count to calculate the proportion of the string that was `c`. I added print statements to investigate why it was wrongly returning `0.0` for a string that had some `c`'s in it.

I have tried declaring the counter as an `int` and then casting it to `double` later but that didn't help.

```
public double cRatio() {
        String dna = "ATCCCCCCGTACCTAGCAA";
        double cCount = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < dna.length(); i++) {
            char ch = dna.charAt(i);
            if (ch == 'c') {cCount++;}
        }
        System.out.println("C Count is : " + cCount);
        System.out.println("dna.length() is : " + dna.length());

        double cgRatio = (cCount / dna.length());
        System.out.println("C Ratio is : " + cgRatio);
        return cgRatio;
    }
```

I expect the counter to have value 9.0 at the time it prints but instead, it is 0.0.

Comment: when `ch == 'C'` the output is `0.47368421052631576`

Comment: the output is correct, as you are counting only lower case char 'c'. If you want to count both then you can convert the ch in lowercase and count.
if (Character.toLowerCase(ch) == 'c')
use this if condition and that should work irrespective of case

Answer (score 3):

Your code does not count the letter `c` because you are checking for the letter `C`. The `small c` does not equal the `upper C` (different [ASCII code](http://www.asciitable.com/)).

```
if (ch == 'C') {cCount++;}
```

This will fix your problem.

Comment: You could also use a if(ch.toUpperCase().equals(‘C’) {cCounter++;} to make it case-insensitive

Comment: Thank you. That was silly.  This method was part of a larger program that earlier on in the processing of inputs converts all inputs to lowercase.  When testing this method in isolation the call to .toLowerCase was outside the scope of the test.